# Change Form when application is working and freezes

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, freeze

I'm developing a C# WinForms application; this application will have many windows to show some reports. These windows are forms created from some DLLs by reflection, so the code is not so simple to change.

The problem is that when a form is getting data or processing some info it freeze/locks all the application, so users can't navigate to other forms in the application. So, if the user wants a report that takes 5 minutes, the app freeze 5 minutes and the user can't navigate to another window.

I have tried to call the new forms with Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate () {}); but it freezes anyway. I tried to use MDI from Windows Forms, but also freezes. I tried to use Document Manager or Tab View from DevExpress, but the same problem.

I also have begun reading the problems to create a form in a new thread with the UI from the main thread, but I think this is not my problem because it's ok for the form to be freeze, but not to freeze all the application and user can navigate other forms.

If I try to create the forms in other process the application loads too slow because all the controls it has, so ideally it must be in the same process.

Is there any way I can call a new form in a new thread, that won't freeze all application while processing? Is there any opensource/paid control that can help me with this problem?

Thanks in advance, regards.

Comment: Your application only has one UI thread which responds to system\GUI events. Any calculations or downloading should be done in a background thread.

Comment: You cannot create, access, or update any UI element from any thread other than the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

Simpliest way to do asynchronous programming in winforms and C# is async/wait logic.

Try something like this :

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

private async void btnDoReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task<bool> reportTask = new Task<bool>(ReportFunction); // if your function is void you can create it as Task reportTask = new Task(ReportFunction)
    trainTask.Start();  // here your task - report is executed asynchronously and GUI does not freeze

    bool reportResult = await  reportTask; // wait on resposne from your reportTask
}

private bool ReportFunction()
{
  // do what ever you need to in this function
  return true;
}
```

You can also use [BackgroundWorker class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker?view=netcore-3.1) which is also working asynchronously and even you can raise event from your asynchronously running thread. After that this event you can catch in main thread - GUI thread, so you will be able to safely access controls of your GUI applications without errors.

```
 using System.ComponentModel;

 private BackgroundWorker bWork = new BackgroundWorker();
 this.bWork.DoWork += BWork_DoWork;
 this.bWork.ProgressChanged += bwork_ProgressChanged;

 private void btnReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     // this will run your code asynchronously
     this.bWork.RunWorkerAsync();
 }

 private void BWork_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
 {
     // here you can create your report

    // if you want you can raise event like this :
     this.bWork.ReportProgress(this)
    // and after raising of above event function : bWork_ProgressChanged is 
    //called where you can safely access main thread controls
 }

                   
 private void bwork_ProgressChanged(object sender, 
 System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
 {
   /* here you can access main thread GUI elements for example progress bar 
   without worrying of some problems because this function is called in 
   main thread space*/
 }
```